# How to export HTML data into Excel in correct format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, excel

I am using `jQuery` to export HTML data into Excel. Data is exporting, but it's not exporting in a correct format. On opening the Excel file it says:

> The file format and extension of "download.xls" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

And when I open it, the data there is present, but badly merged. What should I do?

```
echo "<div id=dvData3>";
//echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=5  cellspacing=0 style=border-collapse: collapse >";

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=14% align=center>Name</td>";
echo "<td width=14% align=center>Grand Total</td>";
echo "<td width=14% align=center>Expanse Type</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($allrows=mysql_fetch_array($newresult1))
{

  $name=$allrows["empid"];
  $gamount=$allrows["gtotal"];
  $exptype=$allrows["expanseType"];

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width=14% align=center>$name</td>";
  echo "<td width=14% align=center>$gamount</td>";
  echo "<td width=14% align=center>$exptype</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=14% align=center>Total Amount</td>";
echo "<td width=14% align=center>$Tamount</td>";

echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<input type='button' id=\"btnExport3\" value=\" Export Table data into Excel \" />"; 

}
```

And here's my jQuery function:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btnExport3").click(function (e) {

      window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData3').html());
      //window.open('data:application/csv,charset=utf-8,' +  $('#dvData').html());
      e.preventDefault(); 

    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/08/11/Excel-Extension-Hardening-and-Web-Applications.aspx

Comment: ...and your table in Excel likely looks bad because it has uneven numbers of columns: last row has only 2 cells, not 3.  Also missing the closing </tr>

Comment: i've added </tr> .. no improvements yet. also error type is 101786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnExport3").click(function(e) {

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('dvData3');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    //setting the file name
    a.download = 'download.xlsx';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: same error. it's not even allowing me to open excel file

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/2u5w0sj.png 
Used the code and got .xls file, same for xlsx

Answer (score -2):

Change the .xls to .xlsx if you have the latest office installed.